# How can I retrieve shared preferences onCreate?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In the preferences I would like to change the preference view according the Unit type(Imprial or metric). On the create method I am checking what was the last value of the
`measurement_unit` preference, but always return metric on the app startup.
I also have a `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` where I am changing the view according the user entry, which is working. How can I get the saved preference when the onCreate is called?

```
public class PrefMainActivity extends PreferenceActivity{
    String TAG="BlueGlucose";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.action_settings);

        this.init_view();

    }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case android.R.id.home:
              finish();
              return true;

          default:
              return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
  }

  SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener spChanged = new
          SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {              
                PrefMainActivity.this.init_view();

            }
// your stuff here
};


    private void init_view(){   
        try
        {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            String metric = getResources().getString(R.string.imperial);

            if (prefs.getString("measurement_unit",metric)  == metric)
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
                    new PrefMainFragmentImperial()).commit();
            else
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
                        new PrefMainFragmentMetric()).commit();


            prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(spChanged);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if (prefs.getString("measurement_unit",metric)  == metric)
```

String in java need to be compared by `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`